# query array of embedded documents in spring data mongodb

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I have simple question:

How do I express this query

```
db.inventory.find( { "instock": { warehouse: "A", qty: 5 } } )
```

[Query for a Document Nested in an Array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/)

in spring data mongoDB, preferably using QueryDSL but other ways are welcome, too.

All my queries so far match fields on any embedded document in the array but I need to match both on the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using Spring Data repository, you could use :

### 1 - @Query annotation

```
@Query("{ 'instock': { 'warehouse': ?0, 'qty': ?1 } }")
List<YourClass> findByInstock(String warehouse, int qty);
```

### 2 - Custom repository method implementation

```
List<YourClass> findByInstock(String warehouse, int qty) {
  return mongoTemplate.find(Query.query(Criteria.where("instock").elemMatch(Criteria.where("warehouse").is(warehouse).and("qty").is(qty)));
```

You can find more material [here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-data/spring-data-add-custom-method-to-repository/) on how to implement this method.
    }

Comment: @user3813234 , did you manage to setup the query or do you need more material?

Comment: Hi, I used your second apprach with the elemMatch. Worked perfectly! Thanks!